# Question about POST method security

Tags: html, security

Let say I have a post from like this:

```
<form action="myApp/form_action.asp" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

So, let say there is a really bad buy who want to do something in my application. For example, my form_action.asp not only accept param "fname", "lname", but also "gender", can he/she make a request on their own , like this....

```
<form action="http://www.myDomain.com/myApp/form_action.asp" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
  Gender: <input type="text" name="gender" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

****Updates:****
I don't want the user submit the gender, because I don't want to modify his/her gender after he/she assigned.

If he/she can submit this query, it there any way to avoid him/her to do so? thank you.

Comment: btw, why your form accepts gender if you don't want it to be submitted? A little more background information would be helpful...

Comment: I want the user assign their gender initially, after that, I won't him/her to reset his / her gender.

Comment: Then just check if the gender is already set. If not, allow it to be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking about this the wrong way. Forget about HTML forms. They're not what your server handles. It handles HTTP requests.

And (pretty obviously) people can send you HTTP requests that contain *whatever they want*. Not just additional fields, but also fields with values that the form would not allow, or fields with names that are 5000 characters long and/or values that are that long.

So what you absolutely must do is define what constitutes valid input and reject input that isn't. In your case, it's pretty simple: if the form is not supposed to contain a "gender" field, then have the server ignore such a field, or abort with an error if it's present.

Usually you don't have to do anything to ignore fields. But you definitely have to write your app in such a way that it does not accept field values that are not valid.

Comment: I updated my question in comment, I want a method that user set their gender, but after he/she set his/her gender, I don't want him/her to change it again.

Comment: @Tattat: the question then becomes ASP-specific. I'm pretty sure there is a way to not have submitted values automatically overwrite server-side data.

Comment: @Tattat: Then you can do this on the server. You can check to see if gender is set, if it is set, throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid this. Inputs coming from the clientside are NEVER secure and can ALWAYS be tampered with.

You'll have to implement your checks serverside, in the ASP file itself.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't avoid it is that he doesn't need to make his own copy and submit it from another domain. He can easily **modify your site live** with javascript (e.g.: firebug) and send the fake request **identical** to a valid one.

Answer (score -1):

If your form action file i.e. form_action.asp doesn't call for the $_POST['gender'] variable i can't see how it would affect your script.

Make sure that you are sanitizing your variables though, so for first name and last name you would only really want to accept A-Za-z, space and maybe hyphens and apostrophes.

By doing this it doesn't really matter what they send to your form because most of the tags, brackets etc will be removed and any script injected won't run.

Make sure you also escape the variables before you enter them in your database, I use mysql_real_escape_string in php, but don't know any asp so you will have to look it up.

Comment: Yeah, because you sure as hell don't want customers from Japan, China, India, Greece, Israel or Russia...